# Build dict applying expressions to an object

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm looking if there is any way to apply operations to an object, and return a dictionary with the result of those operations applied.

This is what I reached so far

```
[{"len": len(s), "slice": s[2:4] } for s in [u'hello']][0]
```

But that feels hackish, because list comprehensions are thought to be used with lists, and not with one object/one result.

I was wondering if there is any direct, better, faster, optimal way to do this in python.

EDIT: I'm looking to solve this using only one expression. I don't want to have more than one line, and [u'hello'] must be executed only once (not once per operation) in the expression.

These two are no solutions:

```
s = [u'hello']
{"len": len(s), "slice": s[2:4] }

{"len": len([u'hello']), "slice": [u'hello'][2:4] }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `s = u'hello'; {"len": len(s), "slice": s[2:4] }`?

Comment: oh! you are right! I missed to say that I'm looking for a one-liner. I'm using this in a part of the code where I wanted to be all together there in one expression. I'll edit accordingly

Comment: "I'm looking for a one-liner" sounds like a silly constraint. If two lines accomplish what you want to do, use two lines and golf them together later.

Comment: You should also consider providing an actual example of the input list, the "operations" to apply, and the desired result, instead of spending most of your question explaining what *doesn't* work.

Comment: Also, are you aware of [`dict` comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't really force the one-liner idea too far when it doesn't fit. However, there is a one-line solution for this:

```
(lambda s: {"len" : len(s), "slice" : s[2:4]})(u'hello')
```

It's a little ugly to read in one line, but it only creates 'hello' once.

Comment: Seeing as `u'hello'` is an immutable literal, wouldn't it only be created once anyway?

Comment: "len" : len(u'hello'), "slice" : u'hello'[2:4] would create two literals. if they were less than 4 characters then some python optimization kicks in to reference the same object (in 2.6 and 2.7 at least). If you had operators that expected the same object to be referenced (not strings), then you might care that the same object is being used in each location with the 's' keyword. I left the comment in as a response to the edit to the question.

Comment: As far as I can tell that is patently false: http://ideone.com/gejbE3. Are you sure you're not trying this out in a REPL where string literals aren't really processed in one "compiler pass"?

Comment: @millimoose: I think that depends upon the implementation-- I just ran your test code with IronPython and got three separate objects.  (CPython, pypy, and jython all gave the same id values.)  I'm not sure what happens if it's all one one line, though. -- update: no, even on the same line, it produces two objects.

Comment: @DSM IronPython might not really be a typical implementation in this respect. I'm guessing it doesn't really produce any equivalent of a `.pyc` module and just more-or-less "naively" translates source code to MSIL, relying on DLR to make the approach perform. (At least in CPython, string literals are "interned" at module scope, implying that this is handled when a module is "compiled". E.g.: all instances of the same literal in a module will have the same `id`, but an identical literal imported from a different module will be a different object.)

Comment: Last but not least, it's vanishingly unlikely that "garbage string literals" will be a serious performance concern for an actual program.

Comment: @millimoose Yup 100% agree with what you said. My comment reflects the len 3 or less global map which lives in Python's string module C file that I explored at one point. The pyc from py conversion has further optimizations that take place if you're in one of the mainstream implementations. The statment just there to answer the specific request of the question, regardless of interpreter optimizations.

Comment: @millimoose: I don't think it matters so much whether it's typical, only whether there's reason to think it's part of the language spec that there's only one literal, and I think that it's not.  Of course, I think the whole question is silly -- this is Python, not GolfScript, and the two-line version is best.

Comment: @Pyrce Right. I guess what I meant to say is that whatever optimisation it is you have in mind is *unrelated to* whether or not string interning goes on, since it seems to for "long" strings in CPython. (And both are internal optimisations, for which the following holds: a) whether or not they occur is unlikely to be critical to the performance of a program as to whether they actually take effect, and b) you can't rely on them either way, as DSM points out.)